# SQL: Split time interval into 1 hour with overlapping minutes split (Bigquery)

Tags: google-bigquery, intervals

This is the data that I have:

| date | event_type | interval_start | interval_end | duration_in_min |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-06-06 | s1 | 09:05:00 | 11:45:00 | 160 |
| 2022-06-01 | s2 | 08:00:00 | 08:17:00 | 17 |
| 2022-05-31 | c1 | 17:55:00 | 18:08:00 | 13 |
| 2022-04-05 | s3 | 07:58:00 | 08:46:00 | 48 |
| ... |  |  |  |  |

and this is what I would like to achieve:

`interval` represents a 1 hour interval (or maybe 59 min and 59 sec to be accurate, in case an event starts/ends at exactly 10:00:00 but it should not occur very often).

| date | interval | event_type | interval_start | interval_end | duration_in_min |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-06-06 | 09:00:00 | s1 | 09:05:00 | 11:45:00 | 55 |
| 2022-06-06 | 10:00:00 | s1 | 09:05:00 | 11:45:00 | 60 |
| 2022-06-06 | 11:00:00 | s1 | 09:05:00 | 11:45:00 | 45 |
| 2022-06-01 | 08:00:00 | s2 | 08:00:00 | 08:17:00 | 17 |
| 2022-05-31 | 17:00:00 | c1 | 17:55:00 | 18:08:00 | 5 |
| 2022-05-31 | 18:00:00 | c1 | 17:55:00 | 18:08:00 | 8 |
| 2022-04-05 | 07:00:00 | s3 | 07:58:00 | 08:46:00 | 2 |
| 2022-04-05 | 08:00:00 | s3 | 07:58:00 | 08:46:00 | 46 |
| ... |  |  |  |  |  |

I struggle to sort the data per hour by getting a split for the overlapping minutes into a new interval(s).

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: I didn't get the pattern of you expected result, could you explain more? For e.g., why  `duration_in_min` turns from 160 to 55 in the first line? What is the calculation to get the 55?

Comment: The event s1 started at 09:05:00 and ended at 11:45:00 and last in total 160 minutes.
As I would like to split the duration per interval of 1 hour, it should be broken down as followed:
09:05:00 - 10:00:00 (or maybe 09:59:59): 55 minutes / 
10:00:00 - 11:00:00 ((or maybe 10:59:59): 60 minutes / 
11:00:00 - 11:45:00: 45 minutes
I should have mentioned that interval 09:00:00 sums up duration_in_minutes between 09:00:00 and 10:00:00

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select 
  date, time(hour, 0, 0) as `interval`, 
  event_type, interval_start, interval_end,
  time_diff(least(time(hour + 1, 0, 0), interval_end), greatest(time(hour, 0, 0), interval_start), minute) as duration_in_min
from your_table, 
unnest(generate_array(0, 23)) hour
where hour between extract(hour from time(interval_start)) and extract(hour from time(interval_end))
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. I get the following error message: "Input calculates to invalid time: 24:00:00"

Comment: you should replace `time(hour + 1, 0, 0)` with `time(hour, 59, 59)`

Comment: I need to compare the results but at first glance it works, at least the query runs.
2 questions: If I remove he event_type. how can I sum the duration_in_min per interval?
And also how can I sort by a string (here 'interval')?

Comment: sure. the only other adjustment you might want to have is to add 1 for `duration_in_min`

Comment: run code against sample data in your question and you will see if you need add 1 or not - it is up to you. as of your extra questions - it is hard to answer those without having more details/context. i would recommend you to post new question with those details as well as input and expected output so we can further help :o)

Comment: Thank you for your time and help Mikhail, it looks like it works perfectly! I'll check the rest tmrw :)

Comment: It looks like the query cannot be used in datastudio. "BigQuery error: Query error: Input calculates to invalid time: 24:00:00". Do you know a work around? I have tried both time(hour + 1, 0, 0) and time(hour, 59, 59) without success

Comment: but same does work just in BigQuery?

Comment: I think original question is fully answered - so looks like your extra comments becoming totally new question!